# Distributed database - Eventual Consistency Implications

Tags: eventual-consistency, distributed-database

I've been learning more about eventual consistency and distributed database, and I have a question.

In my scenario, I have a distributed database that stores some listings users have posted (for example, a real estate listing site). My understanding of one of the effects of eventual consistency is that if I post something and user X does a lookup of my listings, they may not see my post immediately if they are seeing a replicated version of the database which is not yet consistent with the one I posted to.

Now let's say I make a posting and then I logout of the system. I log back in and go to view my own listings. Wouldn't there be a chance that I could login to a replicated version of the database that isn't yet consistent with the one I posted to (similar to the scenario above where another user might not see my listing).

Am I misunderstanding how this works?

EDIT: In this scenario, I'm not necessarily using a master/slave replication technique. But I do have replicated versions of the database for peak load times.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible that when you log in again, you log in to a different version of the database.

This particular case could be corrected by assigning a specific database version or instance identifier to your account, and have the system connect to that version (if possible) on each login.

Comment: Is it common practice to assign an instance to an account? Or are there other ways to handle this?